# model specification problem

Tags: multiple-regression, model-selection

I have the following model that I would like to rebuild:

$Y_{i,t}=a+bx_{i,t}+cx_{i,t-1}+e_{i,t}$

I' am wondering now whether this is the same as the model above:

$Y_{i,t}=a+ d\Delta x_{i,t}+e_{i,t}$, where $\Delta x_{i,t}=x_{i,t} - x_{i,t-1}$?

I believe this is true but i just need to be 100% sure.

Thank you

Comment: I replaced "delta" with "\Delta". Hopefully that's what you intended. If not, you can edit. You should include an edit or additional discussion to clarify your question (see Alexis' answer).

Comment: this is indeed the notation I had in mind. thank you for clarification

Comment: Now that you ask a clear question, it's easy to answer: The two models are not the same, but the second model is a special case of the first, with $b=1$ and $c=-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say a few things.

First, I wonder if your notation is off? In the second model, do you mean: $Y_{i,t}=a+ d\Delta x_{i,t}+e_{i,t}$, where $\Delta x_{i,t}=x_{i,t} - x_{i,t-1}$?

If that is so, then I would say that these models are not equivalent, because there are at least two kinds of short term effects $x$ can have on $Y$ (1) effects of *change* in $x$ (i.e. $\Delta x$), and (2) level effects (i.e. effects of $x$ itself).

Your second model includes only the effects of change in $x$.

You first model includes the effect of the level of $x$, plus an adjustment for the effect of the level of $x$ from last time, which indirectly gives an effect of change in $x$.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! The problem with my data/model is that it puts too much emphasis on the these two variables although in the overall model they "should" only play a tangential role. I was hoping to circumvent this problem by including only the change but as you mentioned I'll loose the level effects. Are there any possibilities to "control" a certain emphasis on model variables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... do mean the effect sizes for your $x$ variables are larger than for some other variables that you care about?

Comment: I was referring to the coefficients. From an economical point of view the coefficients should take on certain levels that "make sense". I fear that my model somehow overestimates the effect of xi,t−xi,t−1 (bookvalues) these values and thus the coefficients are way off values you would expect.

Comment: So it sounds like your expectations may need updating? :)